# I can't tell the difference between the clicked and unclicked link colours in "hot questions"

Tags: bug, design

These colours for clicked and unclicked links are rather similar-looking shades of blue, on the main UX stackexchange page at least. I have to look very carefully to tell the difference. This is not good UX. The particular place I have the issue is in the "hot questions" pane on the right hand side.

Comment: Low contrast between clicked and unclicked links is an issue that affects other sites as well, especially Meta sites. I would post this question on Meta SE. But Meta SE has an answer to a similar question that may be helpful to you; see [New beta style is much harder on my eyes; looking for CSS overrides to fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251475/340816).

Comment: Hmm, I had the feeling that UX was worse than the others, but looking at it again, they seem to be about the same. Must have been in my head.